# incorrect http protocol shown by chrome developer tools?

Tags: python, google-chrome, http2, http-1.1, alpn

I am checking the http protcol in use for this site http://www.dlf.in/
Chrome developer tools shows it to be http/1.1 as in the image below.

However the command line tool [is-http2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-http2-cli) or alpn in python as seems to indicate the http/1.1 is not available. And only http1 is available. What's going on here?

I am doing the ALPN negotiation in python as follows (openssl version : OpenSSL 1.0.2h and python version 3.5.1)

```
import ssl
import socket

port = 443
domain = 'www.dlf.in'

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.set_alpn_protocols(['h2', 'spdy/3.1', 'spdy/3', 'spdy/2', 'http/1.1'])


conn = ctx.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM),
        server_hostname=domain)

conn.connect((domain, port))
print(conn.selected_alpn_protocol())
```

[image: network tab of chrome develper tools for dlf.in]

Answer (score 0):

That site doesn't have HTTPS on it. Browsers only support HTTP/2 over HTTPS despite the spec allowing it over HTTP in theory.

Comment: I want to know why chrome says it supports http/1.1

Comment: I thought you were asking why not HTTP2. Above code is for HTTPS (443) so is not what is on this site (which only uses HTTP - port 80). It's also saying it's powered by IIS not Python. And IIS definitely supports HTTP/1.1 - as do all web servers now a days. As to why your tools are not saying that I've no idea since you've given very little detail here. At present it's really, really unclear what you're asking and seems like you don't know how your system is set up at all!

Answer (score 0):

Using `telnet` and `HTTPie` to send HTTP requests (both 1.0 and 1.1), the web server responds with:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK

I tried it with 2.0 and got:

> HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported

Comment: What is the exact command you are using? Also I don't get it, why it's happening and that's the question I am asking

Comment: Using HTTPie: `http www.dlf.in --print Hh` will print your Request and Response Headers.

Comment: Using Telnet: `telnet www.dlf.in 80`, then typing or pasting in your HTTP Request and Headers will get you a response.

Comment: The server is responding with `http/1.1` responses, not sure why the other tools say that `http/1.1` isn't available..

Comment: Does it mean that although the header is http/1.1 the actual ALPN negotiation fails to negotiate http/1.1.

Comment: That site isn't serving `HTTPS`

Answer (score 0):

This site doesn't support SSL (I tried using using `curl https://www.dlf.in` and got the HTTP 504 response)

[Curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) is a command line browser that also implements HTTP/2 in clear (non SSL) and it has the [upgrade](http://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#iana-h2c) mechanism (using the `--http2` flag). Using that flag I saw that the website doesn't support clear HTTP/2. (There is an option to connect directly with HTTP/2 in clear, without the upgrade mechanism, using `--http2-prior-knowledge`, but it doesn't work either).